# Can't create an object from parameters that are constrained to the object's property types

Tags: typescript

I have a type that represents a couple of alternative message variants ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeAUFKAfKBvKBrCEALigHIBDUgGigDdyAbAVwhNICNSoBfNTHfITYBjanUYs2AEy690AbhQpQkKAGlCAZ2SwEAbVIEQpALqKV0AGoSIAHjUA+HQFEAHsABO5YcFvw4NLhGJGo8Dgb0zBCmisrgVjYAgjrWUbYUpA6xAGZMAHY+AJZweVDCHhDkwBD+AIz2UBDuEHlS2hogmg4AFMHqNJGSUKks9g4AlCT+OHwA9LNQACrxZEFC6vLiUSQjdo6b3FyF2nlwwFDkmpqFAOZ55OwM0MCIFmT+pAB0cwvoy6qkNbEDZbIa7MYHI4nM4XK63e6PZ6vFaAwTAgBEwnRm0GrCg6Kk2J4Xx+6DJ-wg2jg2SgYA8cEgHlAZCMXHIFSghQKcAAtmAqoVEd90PMyWKKWQ1FCoKdzpdrncHk8oC8VSjMeiSSLfmLyeryOj+BrpbLYQqEcrVW9SMbhVBRbrdRKbQaTTD5fClUi1QDbd0AEwAZn9-vGfAqwCYHlKQIGNh4il4KFyBWAxVK5Uq1X8-r8jWarW0-h6fRgBlZJjj21gERspkmukQ2FJzqBUz06KM6LMoLxZfRuO7kM50LlcMViJVyIBHztDqWKLbNc7hCHvfbA5sa8OI5l7vHFu91qXGpxNhIBKJhznOr+8SpNLpDIgTJALMIbI5XOEvP5aaFpKOs6-ZdiYbpjuaXpTj60A2liWpQBGUYxmiVYsAmKC8EAA)):

```
type Foo =
  | { key: 'a', value: 'b' }
  | { key: 'c', value: 'd' }
  ;
```

Here's some helper types & sanity checks as well:

```
type Keys = Foo['key'];  // "a" | "c"
type Value<K> = Extract<Foo, { key: K }>['value'];

type ValueA = Value<'a'>;  // "b"
```

Now, I want to properly type a function `createFoo(key, value): Foo`, but I'm failing. These are the two things I'd thought might work:

```
function createFoo1<K extends Keys>(key: K, value: Value<K>): Foo {
  // Type '{ key: K; value: Value<K>; }' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.
  //   Type '{ key: K; value: Value<K>; }' is not assignable to type '{ key: "c"; value: "d"; }'.
  //     Types of property 'key' are incompatible.
  //       Type 'K' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
  //         Type '"a" | "c"' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
  //           Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"c"'.(2322)
  return { key, value };
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem with that variant is a call like this:

```
const key: Keys = 'a';
const value = 'b';
createFoo1(key, value);
```

Here `key` is "not" known to be 'a' statically, so in general the signature doesn't typecheck.

```
function createFoo2<F extends Foo>(key: F['key'], value: F['value']): Foo {
  // Type '{ key: F["key"]; value: F["value"]; }' is not assignable to type 'Foo'.
  //   Type '{ key: F["key"]; value: F["value"]; }' is not assignable to type '{ key: "c"; value: "d"; }'.
  //     Types of property 'key' are incompatible.
  //       Type 'F["key"]' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
  return { key, value };
}
```

I'd say a similar problem when called like `createFoo2<Foo>(...)`.

Now I'm out of ideas, but it looks like that shouldn't be a too complicated use case. Is there a way to type this?

Comment: You can remove explicit return type and it will be inferred properly https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeAUFKAfKBvKBrCEALigHIBDUgGigDdyAbAVwhNICNSoBfNTHfITYBjanUYs2AEy690AbhQpQkKAGlCAZ2SwEAbVIEQpALqKV0AGoSIAHjUA+HQFEAHsABO5YcFvw4NLhGJGo8Dgb0zBCmisrgVjYAgjrWUbYUpA6xAGZMAHY+AJZweVDCHhDkwBD+AIz2UBDuEHlS2hogmg4AFMHqNJGSUKks9g4AlDh8FcBMHqVBhAM2PIq8KLkFwMWl5ZXV-gBMfo3Nrdr+PX0wBkamy1EkN6SD0SaT2NMQs-MCRg8sVYodbCEqaYBQbIIWo6PZVGrQ7oZGgcUjjeRQAD0mL+QigACJyPiMa8SPj2MSeEpQXlwZCEIdYRV4XUkaIUTJ0VicYtiAThJTSQSpJTuEA

Comment: Small correction: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeAUFKAfKBvKBrCEALigHIBDUgGigDdyAbAVwhNICNSoBfNTHfITYBjanUYs2AEy690AbhQpQkKAGlCAZ2SwEAbVIEQpALqKV0AGoSIAHjUA+HQFEAHsABO5YcFvw4NLhGJGo8Dgb0zBCmisrgVjYAgjrWUbYUpA6xAGZMAHY+AJZweVDCHhDkwBD+AIz2UBDuEHlS2hogmg4AFMHqNJGSUKks9g4AlDh8FcBMHqVBhAM2PIq8KLkFwMWl5ZXV-gBMfo3Nrdr+PX0wBkamy1EkN6SD0SaT2NMQs-MCRg8sVYodbCEqaYBQbIIWpPBA6PZVGrQ7oZGgcUjjeRQAD02L+QigACJyISsa8SIT2KSeEpQXlwZCEIdYYgkGUKoijijRGiZJicXjFsQicJqeSiVJqdwgA
you tested `createFoo1` twice, and I added checks that the result objects are assignable to `Foo` - variant 1 ok

Comment: @AlekseyL. The actual problem happens in a different context, the `Foo` is actually sent somewhere else and not returned. So, if I want to check whether a proper `Foo` was constructed, I have to do it at the call site, not at the caller.